# Why is it not returning the values of INDEX formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, unique

I'm using Excel 2016 and I'm finding for unique data from an array using INDEX, MATCH, and COUNT formula as follows;

```
{=INDEX(list,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(uniquelist,list),0))}
```

list = table[column_name] and uniquelist = $columnRow($B2:B2). I tried putting hard values and the results are the same.
My logic is simple; count the list with initial empty cell. That returns {0,0,..} array which gives MATCH(0,{0,0,..},0). That gives first index of matched value. So, I got INDEX(list,1) and it should return the first item, not 0.

I have tried searching on the Internet, and some people use new formula UNIQUE which is available only for Office365. I am getting 0 only and when I try to evaluate my formula, it shows the correct result until the last step.

**My formula**

[image: My formula with the list]

Am I using the wrong formula? I don't want to simply copy&paste with "Remove Duplicates" feature built-in Excel.

Comment: Do you have some sample markdown data to work with?

Comment: Sorry, I was adding picture link https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaPkh.png

Comment: Ok, so if your data is in `A1:A8`, are you sure you used: `=INDEX(A$2:A$8,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(B$1:B1,A$2:A$8),0))`, entered through CSE?

Comment: Yes as it's array method, I use CSE for {}. I even tried to prevent some empty cells or data error check method such as IFERROR, but for now I remove them.

Comment: The formula I just gave works a 100% on the data you showed though (at least on my end)

Comment: That's why I'm so confused why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: You have to start your formula in `B2`, not `B1`

Comment: It's the same. I tried it. I just don't know how to do at this point.

Comment: You have to delete cell `B1` and insert a header which wont appear in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/remove-or-allow-a-circular-reference-8540bd0f-6e97-4483-bcf7-1b49cd50d123#:~:text=If%20this%20confuses%20you%2C%20imagine,the%20formula%20in%20the%20cell](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/remove-or-allow-a-circular-reference-8540bd0f-6e97-4483-bcf7-1b49cd50d123#:%7E:text=If%20this%20confuses%20you%2C%20imagine,the%20formula%20in%20the%20cell).

**Turn on Iterative Calculation**

I HATE it when the application prevents the client's work with just a warning just because it may has impact on performance. Of course, my bad for not reading carefully every time a warning dialog box appears.